# How can i point 2 domain to one root direction

Tags: ispconfig-3

I want to point 2 domain names to one root direction to use.
So both domains can be use this directions contents : /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web
How can i do that in ispconfig?

It's running on nginx on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate as below,

`Select the second domain` > `Options` > `Apache Directives`

and input the following directive.

**For Apache:**

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/clients/client0/web6/web"
```

**For nginx:**

```
root /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web;##merge##
```

Restart apache/nginx, now both the domains should now point to the same root directory.